# How do you filter a SharePoint list based on a current user's email. (Guest users)

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-accounts, sharepoint-list-filter, guest-access

I have a modern SharePoint Online Team Site where users that are external to the organization have been granted guest access.

There is a list that has a column containing various email addresses related to those guests.

Is there any way I can filter the list or create a view that only shows items that have an email address in that column matching their account's email?

[Me] only seems to work for internal users and only for a Person or Created by field. Is there another function that can be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, filter supported for users inside your organization, otherwise build your custom view with SPFX

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter in the modern experience. Select the email value you want.
[image]